# MySql | select all with inner join, without duplicate values

Tags: mysql

this is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM Products as pr
INNER JOIN Customers as ct
ON ct.supplierUUID = pr.supplierUUID
LEFT JOIN FavoriteProducts as fp
ON ct.customerUUID = fp.favoriteCustomerUUID
WHERE ct.customerUUID = '101049356085569448728'
```

I get the following result:

```
+------------+-------------+--------+------------------+-------------+ ... and so
|productsID  |productName  | price  |favoriteProductID |customerID   | 
+------------+-------------+--------+------------------+-------------+
| 1          |  apple      | 3      | 1                | 123         |
+------------+-------------+--------+------------------+-------------+
| 1          |  apple      | 3      | 1                | 123         | 
+------------+-------------+--------+------------------+-------------+
| 2          | computer    | 10     | 2                | 123         |
+------------+-------------+--------+------------------+-------------+ 
| 2          | computer    | 10     | 2                | 123         |
+------------+-------------+--------+------------------+-------------+
```

How to select everything without duplicate ?

I want the result to be like this:

```
+------------+-------------+--------+------------------+-------------+ ... and so
|productsID  |productName  | price  |favoriteProductID |customerID   | 
+------------+-------------+--------+------------------+-------------+
| 1          |  apple      | 3      | 1                | 123         |
+------------+-------------+--------+------------------+-------------+
| 2          | computer    | 10     | 2                | 123         |
+------------+-------------+--------+------------------+-------------+
```

I try to add GROUP BY but I got error

```
SELECT * FROM Products as pr
Inner JOIN Customers as ct
ON ct.supplierUUID = pr.supplierUUID
LEFT JOIN FavoriteProducts as fp
ON ct.customerUUID = fp.favoriteCustomerUUID
where ct.customerUUID = '101049356085569448728'
**GROUP BY pr.productID**;
```

Thx !!

Comment: read mysql `GROUP BY` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: @tcadidot0  group by without aggregation?

Comment: Sample data would be useful.

Comment: Oh I thought there was one.. my bad @P.Salmon

Comment: `Error Code: 1055. Expression #15 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'tostit.fp.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: group by is inappropriate without aggregations (which you don't have)

Comment: Sorry @Avichai , that's my mistake. but it can work as long as you have aggregation like adding `COUNT(*)` in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY all, the , columns , in select, except, for , COUNT(*)`.. Otherwise, scaisEdge answer should work

Answer (score 0):

You could use DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT productsID, productName, price, favoriteProductID, customerID   
FROM Products as pr
INNER JOIN Customers as ct ON ct.supplierUUID = pr.supplierUUID
LEFT JOIN FavoriteProducts as fp ON ct.customerUUID = fp.favoriteCustomerUUID
WHERE ct.customerUUID = '101049356085569448728'
```